# Help in this sentence

Tags: translation

それは横恋慕と、失恋と…そして成長の歌。

I would translate it as: a love affair, a broken heart (like unrequited love) and a song of growth. I'm particularly interested in the first 2 parts of the sentence.

Comment: So... what exactly is your question? Are you asking what it means?

Comment: Yes, particularly the first part: それは横恋慕と It would be something like prohibited love but I would like to know if I'm right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"横恋慕と、失恋と…そして成長の" all modifies the 歌. Translate it like "(It's) the song of A, B ...and C".

**EDIT:** 横恋慕 means falling in love with someone who is already in a romantic relationship with someone else. 失恋 is heartbreak. So this song starts from a 横恋慕, and then heartbreaking follows, and it ends with overcoming the heartbreak and growing up.

Comment: I see thanks XD. One last thing. Can you translate A and B? それは横恋慕と and 失恋と

Comment: And how would you translate それは横恋慕と as a whole?

Comment: @Est One dictionary says it's "illicit love", but my English is not good and I'm not sure how this word is used. Maybe you can wait for someone else who can give a nice translation.

Comment: Forgetting about the exact translation, why would it be illicit?

Comment: @Est Well, 横恋慕 just means liking someone who already has a partner, and if I understand correctly that thing itself is not "illicit". The word does not necessarily mean actually trying to steal him/her from his/her partner.

Comment: This is the context: a girl is in love with a guy. The guy gets a girlfriend. The girl says she wanted to win and be number 1 for him but loses instead. With this context, your opinion is that the illicit love is that? Basically that she'd like to break them apart.

Comment: Oh, please forget "illicit", I'm not a native speaker of English and I don't really know much about how to use it in this context. 横恋慕 is a fairly neutral word in terms of ethics, and maybe something like "love triangle" should not be far from 横恋慕 in this context.

Comment: More context, the next day the girl makes the boy cheat on his girlfriend (she uses sex appeal). in your opinion that would be the reason for it to be a "forbidden" love?

Comment: Didn't I clearly say that I was not sure if "illicit" is the right word here? Whether it's forbidden or not is up to the readers' judgement. Generally speaking, we should not blindly believe the dictionary definition.